# exception in voice recognition android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I want to recognize voice from audio. It will show the recognized words to list view. I wrote a code to perform the work but get an fatal exception "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException".

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textshow);
    vButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
    lView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    vButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        ArrayList<String> result=data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,result));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

what is the reason of such exception? How can i solve it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because your device doesn't support that intent, use :

```
try {
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
   Log.e("speech", e.toString());
}
```

and try to test on a device that has speech recognizer then see how it goes.

Also take a look here : [ActivityNotFoundException + speech on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D%20ActivityNotFoundException%20speech%20is:question)